Project not starting in expo
I'm working on a mobile application using React Native with Expo. During the development phase, I ran the program in android studio. Now I am trying to run it in the Expo Go app on Android, but it won't start.
When I try to run the program, it is showing this error message:
Trying to use npx expo start
I uninstall Global Expo CLI,uninstalled the .expo folder, Install Expo CLI Locally, upgraded my sdk version, and more but none of them worked for me.

Try the command from a command prompt window opened as Administrator, Also try unistalling npm and re-installing it as admin
